# How to populate an array BEFORE mounted lifecycle hook

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, amcharts

I have a simple API call in getFeedingsAgain. I am calling it inside "beforeMount" yet I can see via my console.logs that my data value for "catFeedingsAgain" stays empty once "mounted" is called. I am trying to populate the catFeedingsAgain array BEFORE the component's "mounted()" lifecycle hook is called so a function I have inside the "mounted()" hook can use that array data. How can I make this work?

Thank you for your time.

UPDATED: including entire component code now.

NOTE: I am basically trying to replace the initial array within Amcharts...Line Chart #2...."dataProvider" with the resultant array from the API call in getFeedingsAgain.

```

```
<template>
  <!-- second chart group -->
  <div class="chart-block" style="padding-top:50px">
    {{ message }}
    <div ref="line" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 50%; height: 30px;"></div>
    <div ref="column" style="vertical-align: middle;display: inline-block; width: 50%; height: 30px;"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios';

  export default {
    props: ['message'],
    name: 'app',
    computed:{

    },
    created(){
      this.getFeedingsAgain(this.message);
    },
    data() {
      return {
        chartCatID: this.message,
        catFeedingsAgain: [],
        catMedicationsAgain: [],
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      /**
       * Line Chart #2
       */
      // this.getFeedingsAgain(this.message);
      console.log("mounted");
      console.log(this.catFeedingsAgain);
      // TODO: line = weight(waf) / day(created?)
      AmCharts.makeChart( this.$refs.line, {
        "type": "serial",
        "dataProvider": [ {
          "day": 1,
          "weight_after_food": 120
        }, {
          "day": 2,
          "weight_after_food": 54
        }, {
          "day": 3,
          "weight_after_food": -18
        }, {
          "day": 4,
          "weight_after_food": -12
        }, {
          "day": 5,
          "weight_after_food": -51
        }, {
          "day": 6,
          "weight_after_food": 12
        }, {
          "day": 7,
          "weight_after_food": 56
        }, {
          "day": 8,
          "weight_after_food": 113
        }, {
          "day": 9,
          "weight_after_food": 142
        }, {
          "day": 10,
          "weight_after_food": 125
        } ],
        "categoryField": "day",
        "autoMargins": false,
        "marginLeft": 0,
        "marginRight": 5,
        "marginTop": 0,
        "marginBottom": 0,
        "graphs": [ {
          "valueField": "weight_after_food",
          "showBalloon": false,
          "lineColor": "#ffbf63",
          "negativeLineColor": "#289eaf"
        } ],
        "valueAxes": [ {
          "gridAlpha": 0,
          "axisAlpha": 0,
          "guides": [ {
            "weight_after_food": 0,
            "lineAlpha": 0.1
          } ]
        } ],
        "categoryAxis": {
          "gridAlpha": 0,
          "axisAlpha": 0,
          "startOnAxis": true
        }
      } );

      /**
       * Column Chart #2
       */
      // TODO: column = dose(dosage) / day(created?)
      AmCharts.makeChart( this.$refs.column, {
        "type": "serial",
        "dataProvider": [ {
          "day": 1,
          "value": -5
        }, {
          "day": 2,
          "value": 3
        }, {
          "day": 3,
          "value": 7
        }, {
          "day": 4,
          "value": -3
        }, {
          "day": 5,
          "value": 3
        }, {
          "day": 6,
          "value": 4
        }, {
          "day": 7,
          "value": 6
        }, {
          "day": 8,
          "value": -3
        }, {
          "day": 9,
          "value": -2
        }, {
          "day": 10,
          "value": 6
        } ],
        "categoryField": "day",
        "autoMargins": false,
        "marginLeft": 0,
        "marginRight": 0,
        "marginTop": 0,
        "marginBottom": 0,
        "graphs": [ {
          "valueField": "value",
          "type": "column",
          "fillAlphas": 1,
          "showBalloon": false,
          "lineColor": "#ffbf63",
          "negativeFillColors": "#289eaf",
          "negativeLineColor": "#289eaf"
        } ],
        "valueAxes": [ {
          "gridAlpha": 0,
          "axisAlpha": 0
        } ],
        "categoryAxis": {
          "gridAlpha": 0,
          "axisAlpha": 0
        }
      } );
    },
    methods:{
      getFeedingsAgain(value) {
        axios.get(`${process.env.KITTY_URL}/api/v1/feedings/?cat__slug&cat__name=${value}`)
          .then(response => {
            console.log("getFeedingsAgain: ");
            console.log(response.data.results);
            this.catFeedingsAgain = response.data.results
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      },
      getMedicationsAgain(value) {
        axios.get(`${process.env.KITTY_URL}/api/v1/medications/?cat__slug=&cat__name=${value}`)
          .then(response => {console.log("catMedications: ");console.log(response.data.results); this.catMedications = response.data.results})
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      },
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  .amcharts-chart-div a{
    text-indent: -9999px;
    outline: none;
  }
</style>
```

```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also create a watcher, to perform an action when the variable changes.

something like this

```
watch: {
  catFeedingsAgain: function() {
    AmCharts.makeChart( this.$refs.line, {
      "type": "serial",
      "dataProvider": this.catFeedingsAgain,
      ...
    });
  }
},
```

you can find the documentation here; https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: this might be what I'm hunting for.  The example at the link you provided has my poor head spinning. I've updated my post to show my entire component. Can you show me what it should look like?

Comment: just place the watch block under your data block (or somewhere else if you prefer), and then move your code for generating charts into the function within the watcher.

Comment: yep was it. Now I just need to figure out how to make it so each time I load this component it gets the current cats line info.

Comment: hahaaa....the "updated" hook solved my newest problem...now the chart updates each time I select a new cat! Awesome. thank you for your time ❤️

Comment: great that you got it working, the ´create method´ you already have should update the component each time you use it. - edit: you figured it out, great :)

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch the data when the view is created and the data is already being observed and this is happens at `created` hook.

```
// rename beforeMount -> created
created(){
  this.getFeedingsAgain(this.message);
}
```

From [`Vue`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) `created` docks

> At this stage, the instance has finished processing the options which
> means the following have been set up: data observation, computed
> properties, methods, watch/event callbacks. However, the mounting
> phase has not been started

Seems like this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use `beforeMount()` method. Avoid it as much as you can. Instead use `created()` life-cycle method:

```
created() {
      this.getFeedingsAgain(this.message);
}
```

Second, you want **to populate an array before mounted is called**. But since your data is being loaded from API asynchronously, you cannot do that. You cannot stop/pause `mounted` event from happening. Vue.js doesn't know when API response will be available. It could take 2 seconds, 3 seconds or simply fail.

The only option you have is to use `v-if` in your template. As long as your array length is zero, you can hide DOM elements or show loading progress bar.

First, you should not use `beforeMount()` method. Avoid it as much as you can. Instead use `created()` life-cycle method:

```
created() {
      this.getFeedingsAgain(this.message);
}
```

Second, you want **to populate an array before mounted is called**. But since your data is being loaded from API asynchronously, you cannot do that. You cannot stop/pause `mounted` event from happening. Vue.js doesn't know when API response will be available. It could take 2 seconds, 3 seconds or simply fail.

The only option you have is to use `v-if` in your template. As long as your array length is zero, you can hide DOM elements or show loading progress bar.

Finally, you may want to initialize some sort of Chart, then you can use Vue.js watcher or initialize it within the `then()` block of the API.

### EDIT

I have to do this, then I will use watcher if I wish to initialize Charting component on every change like this:

```
watch: {
    catFeedingsAgain() {
        AmCharts.makeChart(this.$refs.line, {
            "type": "serial",
            "dataProvider": this.catFeedingsAgain,
        });
    }
},
```

If I have to do this only once, then I would something like this:

```
methods: {
    getFeedingsAgain(value) {
        axios.get(`${process.env.KITTY_URL}/api/v1/feedings/?cat__slug&cat__name=${value}`)
        .then(response => {
            this.catFeedingsAgain = response.data.results;
            AmCharts.makeChart(this.$refs.line, {
                "type": "serial",
                "dataProvider": this.catFeedingsAgain,
            });
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    },
}
```

Both are right approaches. It all depends upon the context.

Comment: I think your answer MIGHT be what I am looking for. Can you expand on your last sentence "Finally, you may want to initialize some sort of Chart, then you can use Vue.js watcher or initialize it within the then() block of the API." ? I've updated my post to show the entire component.

Comment: your last sentence was the key. However, Keja's answer below provided and example and a referencing url. If I could give you both some credit I would. But thank you.

Comment: @Jessi, It is just like how Keja mentioned it. I just elaborated it in my answer. Please have a look and let me know if you have any questions.